# Swift: Has anyone had code work properly on their device, but not in simulator?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swiftui

I was building an application at the beginning of this year up until around March, and then I took a break and recently wanted to pick it up again. However, my code was behaving differently from when I last used it. I had not made any changes to the code, and strangely even past versions from months prior also weren't working, and those certainly weren't changed.

From some troubleshooting here are things that worked based on this code:

Here is the main ContentView class

```
    var body: some View {
    return ZStack {
        setColor
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        .statusBar(hidden: true)

        VStack(alignment:.trailing){
            VStack{
                DisplayBar(majorKeyManager:majorKeyManager)
            }.zIndex(2.0)
            VStack{
                GuitarView(guitarModel:guitarModel)//.position(x:556, y:220)
            }.padding(.bottom, 20)
            VStack{
                PianoView(pianoModel: pianoModel)//majorKeyManager: majorKeyManager, audioEngine: audioEngine)//.position(x:556,y:600)
            }
        }

    }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)//.padding(10)

}
```

Then here is the GuitarView

```
struct GuitarView: View {

@ObservedObject var guitarModel:GuitarModel

var body: some View {

    var needsMarker = false
    var needsIndexMarker = false
    var needsCapo = false

    return HStack (spacing:0){

        VStack{
            ForEach(0..<guitarModel.numStrings){ stringIndex in
                VStack{
```

Here is the PianoView

```
struct PianoView: View {

@ObservedObject var pianoModel:PianoModel

var body: some View {

    return VStack(alignment:.leading){
        ZStack{
            HStack (spacing:2){ // DRAW WHITE KEYS

                ForEach(0..<self.pianoModel.whiteKeyMap.count){ (keyIndex) -> KeyButtonView in
```

I didn't think it was important to show the details of what is happening within GuitarView/PianoView. They are structured very similarly, except the difference is the PianoView always behaves properly, while the GuitarView is hit or miss. I placed a red line in the GuitarView image that shows where it is not entering the ForEach, yet it is meeting the conditions of the ForEach (the variable it is checking is always 12).

Both views are being updated based on their respective models which are ObservedObjects. The model is correctly being updated for both the Guitar and Piano. However, GuitarView gets called once when the initial program is launched, but is sometimes never called again. However, this varies depending on whether I'm running it within device simulator, versus a real device and which XCode version I am using.

On XCode 11.4.1, the code does not work properly on the device simulator on any device (Mac, iPhone, iPad, etc.). However, it does run properly on real devices like an iPhone and an iPad. I tried reinstalling XCode but that changed nothing.

Then, I tried rolling back my version of XCode to 11.2.1, and the code runs properly in the iPad simulator, but not as a Mac simulator.

Has anyone had any similar problems to this? I can't seem to figure out why this code gets called once, but then never gets called again despite its ObservedObject being clearly updated, and another nearly identical view (PianoView), is clearly working.

Comment: By my experience 11.2 was stable, and now use 11.4 - stable.

Comment: Try cleaning your project

Comment: I have tried cleaning my project. And using 11.4 caused all simulators to not work.